# Using Facebook publish_actions on a live event and getting the app reviewed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a Facebook app to be used in live events (ie: concerts, conferences, etc).

So the guests would enroll to the event connecting with Facebook Login and asking the publish_actions permission.

The guest will have an Access Card (RFID chip) that identifies himself and links in our database to his Facebook Access token.

Then, during the event, I would like that some actions made by the guests in the event to trigger some actions on Facebook, this actions will be triggered by different applications that communicate with our servers, our servers will comunicate with Facebook API to trigger actions on Facebook.

So when the guest does check in at the event, his Access Card is scanned by the event staff, and then should automatically post a message on his timeline indicating that he is at that event, sharing a link with more details about that event.

We also want to have a physical Photo Booth where the guest has his Access Card scanned, and then takes a picture that should be automatically posted on his timeline too.

So this is not the typical Facebook app flow, as the content is posted automatically by actions made by the user, but managed by our software instead of actions directly triggered by the user himself.
I'm not sure if this kind of application is allowed on Facebook and if it's allowed, how would the review process be done, as this can't be tested using a website or phone app.

Did someone make something similar or knows the best approach in getting this approved on Facebook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user MUST login with Facebook and authorize your App. People have tried those things with a specific device where people could login, but Facebook detects multiple logins on one device and may block your App. So the only way is to let people use their own device/smartphone to authorize your App. For example, you could offer them a QR tag with a link to the login flow.

The problem with authorizing before the event and storing a Token is that an Extended User Token is valid for 60 days. So if a user enrolls and the event is 61 days later, the Access Token will not work anymore - unless the User refreshes the Token by visiting your App. So before letting him do this before the event, you can just as well let him authorize the App at the event date.

A specific App for the event is surely the safest way, of course.

Comment: Sure, but each user enrolls using their own device days or months before the event happens, so we get an access token, our servers will use the extended access token during the event for triggering this actions. So the user will not have to login on Facebook during the event on the same machine. If that flow is not allowed, then the only way to do this is creating a specific mobile app for the event each user must install?

Comment: oh, that tiny sentence i missed, i will add some more info to my answer

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the 60 days validity for the extended user token, we have made events like this before the mandatory login review for permissions like publish_actions and people had to login with facebook days before the event, but it never was over 60 days. My primary concern, is how would I get Facebook to review an app like this, when all the publish_actions are made by our servers and not by the user himself. I also don't see how the flow could be changed to work with a specific event app, as it would require user interaction.

Comment: it depends when you publish something. if it is ALWAYS user intended, there should be no problem. if you post something in the background without the user doing something actively, it will be a problem and most likely it will not get approved. in your case, the user does indeed trigger the action.

Comment: Yeah, the Facebook posts will always be triggered with real user actions during the event, like checking in, using the photo booth, accesing to a specific stage, etc. I am aware that posting random stuff not related with real user activities is not allowed. But how could I provide Facebook a way of validating / testing this functionality?

Comment: yeah, the testing part could be interesting...maybe you could create a test page where facebook could login, authorize and have some buttons for all the different actions normally happening with rfid...